# Proving $f$ to be homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following question from Wayne Patty's Topology page no. 154.

> Let $(X,T)$ be a countably compact space , let $(Y,U)$ be first countable space , and let $f: Y$$\to X$ be a continuous bijection. Prove that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

I tried it 5 months back but couldn't solve it. I didn't posted it due to my illness and I am self learner so I don't have any help.

Any help please.

Comment: You couldn't solve it because it is not true. Consider the standard example of continuous bijection which is not a homeomorphism $[0,1)\to S^1$ which satisfies your conditions.

Comment: According to the [book](https://books.google.co.ke/books?id=FhTn0Vr8UOQC&lpg=PP8&hl=pl&pg=PA154#v=onepage&q&f=false) there is a typo in the question, it should be $f : X \to Y$. Then with one more assumption the statement becomes true - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prove this because it isn't true.

Let $X$ be the set $\{0, 1\}$ under the discrete topology (all sets are open), and let $Y$ be the set $\{0, 1\}$ under the indiscrete topology (only $Y$ and $\emptyset$ are open).

$X$ is finite, hence compact, hence countably compact.

$Y$ is finite, hence first countable.

The "identity" map $X \to Y$ defined by $f(x) = x$ is a continuous bijection.

However, there is no homeomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: "However, there is no homeomorphism between X and Y." Why so?

Comment: @James The statement “there is a set which is not open” is true in $Y$ but false in $X$, so they can’t be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the other answer, the statement is false. But a similar one is true:

> **Theorem.** Let $(X, T)$ be a countably compact space, let $(Y, U)$ be a first countable Hausdorff space and let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous bijection. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

The new statement differs from the previous one by swapping $X$ and $Y$ in $f : Y \to X$ (which makes way more sense) and additionally assuming that $Y$ be Hausdorff.

**Proof of Theorem.** It suffices to show that the image of any closed subset of $X$ is closed. Assume for contradiction that for some closed $A \subseteq X$ the set $f[A] \subseteq Y$ is not closed and take $b \in \operatorname{cl} f[A] \setminus f[A]$. By assumption $b$ has a countable neighborhood basis $\left< B_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right>$. Let $A_n = \operatorname{cl} \big( A \cap f^{-1}[B_n] \big)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $b \in \operatorname{cl} f[A]$, the family $\{ A_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has the finite intersection property, so by countable compactness we can find some $a \in\bigcap \limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$. Clearly $a \in A$, so $b \neq f(a)$ as $b \notin f[A]$. Take disjoint open neighborhoods $U, V \subseteq Y$ of $f(a)$ and $b$ respectively. Without loss of generality $V = B_n$ for some $n$. Then $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$ and $a \in f^{-1}[U]$. On the other hand $a \in \operatorname{cl} \big( f^{-1}[B_n] \big)$, which is a contradiction.